# Why does terminal prompt text becomes black when connecting to Ubuntu with Nomachine NX client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, nx-client

I'm using Nomachine NX client for Windows to remotely connect to my Ubuntu.

Every now and then I experience a strange phenomena: the text in the prompt of all open terminal windows becomes black, so it can't be viewed over the black background. Typed commands are also black, but the results are in normal colors. So I can run stuff, but can't see what I'm typing...

After I close all open terminal windows and start a new terminal window, everything goes back to normal.

This is rerally annoying and happens quite often. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the terminal needs resetting. Try the `reset` command (you'll have to type it blind, so press Ctrl-C first. It could be that the terminal echo has been turned off (equivalent to `stty -echo`). This type of thing sometimes happens when you `cat` a binary file.

Comment: I was waiting for the situation to happen so I could test your solution, Unfortunately, it doesn't help.